what the max number of page fault will occur
In a system that uses on-demand paging, each page is 4096 bytes in size. The xload rX, rY, addr instruction loads the content from the address addr into the two registers rX and rY, respectively. Each of the two words is 32 bits in size. The size of the xload instruction is 6 bytes.
What is The maximum number of PAGE FAULTS will occur when the processor finishes executing the instruction located at address 24570 and executes the xload instruction that follows?enter image description here
I don’t understand how to solve this. I would appreciate an explanation. Thank you.

You are asked for maximum number of page faults in an on-demand system; what does that mean? This is, strictly speaking, underconstrained but we can assume this means that you should assume first access to each page would result in page fault, and subsequent accesses to same page wouldn't. So, take a long hard look at all you are given, and write down ALL the memory accesses caused by xload instruction (hint - that includes xload instruction itself) Group them into pages. Then note it is said the processor has just finished the previous instrucion - take that into account also

if i knew what i need to calculate and how to do this exactly probably i wouldnt ask for help. basiclly what i need is to someone to tell me what to do and why step by step
